# Sorting ArrayList in C#

Tags: c#

I am using c# language and doing this on console based application. The problem i am having is sorting alphabetically. I add products and quantity myself so there is no fixed arraylist as such. i want to know how to sort it based on what i enter into the console. does this make sense? Where would i enter the code to do this? i  have tried as you can see here i highlighted it. but it comes up with errors such as {"Specified cast is not valid."} and "when casting from a number, the value must be less than infinity.

Edit : the program is now showing only description and price, i am trying to get it to also show quantity. i tried to enter "int q" then quantity = q but i am getting the error of "Error  2   Type 'TheosVendingMachine.Merchandise' already defines a member called 'Merchandise' with the same parameter types  !

```
     public string getDescription()
    {
        return this.description;
    }
    public double getPrice()
    {
        return this.price;
    }
   public int getQuantity()
    {
        return this.quantity;
    }
    //a simple constructor
    public Merchandise(string n, double id )
  * { description = n; price = id;  }*


    // a simple ToString, always good to have around!
    public override string ToString()
    { return description + " (£ " + price + ")" + quantity; }



 public class Merchandise
{
    private string description;
    private double price;
    public Merchandise(string aDescription, double aPrice)
    {
        this.description = aDescription;
        this.price = aPrice;
    }
    public string getDescription()
    {
        return this.description;
    }
    public double getPrice()
    {
        return this.price;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        bool result;
        if (other == null)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Merchandise merchandise = (Merchandise)other;
            result = (this.description.Equals(merchandise.description) && this.price == merchandise.price);
        }
        return result;
    }
 public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.description + " at £ " + this.price;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why on earth are you using `ArrayList` in the first place? `List<T>` was the replacement for it in .NET 2.0, and `ArrayList` has been on the "don't use" list for quite a while.

Comment: Because i am new to this pardon me, i am doing this for coursework and lecturers are behind 1000 years so this is all the help i had access to.

Comment: Can you maybe add a paragraph to this question stating in completeness what you're actually trying to do? That would give us an idea of what you want to accomplish and allow us to better point you in the right direction.

Comment: You may want to tell your lecturers that we are laughing at them over here. And we don't thank them for teaching new developers to use obsolete classes.

Comment: You honestly dont think we have complained a million times to these 60 year old lecturers who have never coded in the real world? and learnt from books. Anyway can someone just please tell me how to do this.

Comment: I'm 60 and have learned about List<T> only this year ;-)

Comment: Not against age just saying my lecturers are ought to go and practice code before they teach new developers.

Comment: Sure. What is `Merchandise`?

Comment: It is the Class for me to be able to add products. http://imgur.com/6Aa9Mj3 This is my program after Adding some products i would then select show merchandise, which in turn when it displays the merchandise i would like to be in alphabetical order

Answer (score 0):

Just Create a List. It's much easier.

```
//Instantiate List
List<string> itemList = new List<string>();

//Create List
itemList.Add("Zomato");
itemList.Add("Carrot");
itemList.Add("Banana");

//Sort List
itemList.Sort();

//Display List
foreach(string item in itemList){
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: How does this allow me to enter my own products within my console application?

Comment: This is an example of how to use a List<T>. You replace it with List<Merchandise>. If that class is comparable the call to Sort is very simple, as you can see. If it insn't one could use Linq instead or make it comparable..

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use the old-fashioned `ArrayList` you can still use its `Sort` method, provided your class implentes `IComparable`.

Since you have not shown us the class `Merchandise` I can only show you an example.

Here is a your Merchandise class with made `IComparable`:

```
public class Merchandise : IComparable
{
    private string description;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;

    public Merchandise(string aDescription, double aPrice)
    {
        this.description = aDescription;
        this.price = aPrice;
    }

    public Merchandise(string aDescription, double aPrice, int aQuantity)
    {
        this.description = aDescription;
        this.price = aPrice;
        this.quantity = aQuantity;
    }

    public string getDescription()  {  return this.description;  }
    public double getPrice()        {  return this.price;        }
    public int getQuantity()        {  return this.quantity;     }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        bool result;
        if (other == null) result = false;
        else
        {
            Merchandise merchandise = (Merchandise)other;
            result = (this.description.Equals(merchandise.description)
                      && this.price == merchandise.price);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object o2)
    {
        if (o2 == null) return 1;
        Merchandise m2 = o2 as Merchandise;
        if (m2 != null) return this.description.CompareTo(m2.description);
        else throw new ArgumentException("Object is not Merchandise ");
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return description + " (£ " + price + ")" + quantity; 
    }
}
```

Note especially the `CompareTo` method! `IComparable` needs only tis method and now you can use the `ArrayList.Sort` on your class. If is really simple since it can rely on the string members to be `Comparable`.

More complex comparisons will be coded directly; in your program you probably want to use a Name member not an ID for the comparison..

Comment: thank you for the help, this is my merchandise class if it helps?

Comment: Well all you need to do is add the `CompareTo` method to your class, pretty much as it is - only change the member  `MerchandiseID`  to `description`! Also add the IComparable to the class declaration! Then the sort should work.

Comment: I have a new problem which i think is quick to fix if you guys can please look

Comment: Looking at the edited code I am confused, maybe the class is not shown correctly? Of course you can't have multiple constructors with the same __'signature'__ i.e. the same parameterlist. ('Same' meanig types and order of the parameters.) Also both the constructor and the ToString method appear to be __outside__ the class code..?! Please edit the code so that it accurately reflects the current Merchandise class! Then we'll see about the remaining problems, ok?

Comment: Not sure where the problems is; I have changed my answer to contain your Marchandise class, including a quantity and the IComparable interface.